# Print Pascal's triangle in Python properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pascals-triangle

I have coded a [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) program in Python, but the triangle is printing as a right angled triangle.

```
n = int(input("Enter the no. of rows: "))
for line in range(1, n + 1):
    c = 1
    x = n
    y = line

    for i in range(1, line + 1):

        print(c, end = " ")
        c = int(c * (line - i) / i)
    print(" ")
```

This gives the output as

```
Enter the no. of rows: 5
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
```

But I want it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyH58.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply just modify your existing code with 2 modifications -

1. Before each line, add `(n-line)` spaces
2. Center align each of the 1 or 2 digit numbers into a 4 alphabet space (changing this yields interesting skewed results :))

```
n=8
for line in range(1, n + 1):
    c = 1
    x=n
    y=line
    #######
    print("  "*(n-line), end="") # This line adds spaces before each line
    #######
    for i in range(1, line + 1):
        ########
        print(str(c).center(4), end = "") # This center aligns each digit
        ########
        c = int(c * (line - i) / i)
    print(" ")
```

#### Output

```
               1
             1   1
           1   2   1
         1   3   3   1
       1   4   6   4   1
     1   5   10  10  5   1
   1   6   15  20  15  6   1
 1   7   21  35  35  21  7   1
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than use a fixed number width, let's try to make the triangle self-adjust:

```
rows = int(input("Enter the no. of rows: "))

triangle = []

for row in range(1, rows + 1):
    c = 1

    numbers = []

    for i in range(1, row + 1):
        numbers.append(c)
        c = c * (row - i) // i

    triangle.append(numbers)

last_row = triangle[-1]
number_width = len(str(max(last_row))) + 1
triangle_width = number_width * len(last_row)

for row in triangle:
    string = ""

    for number in row:
        number_string = str(number)
        string += number_string + ' ' * (number_width - len(number_string))

    print(string.center(triangle_width))
```

And take advantage of that `str.center()` method!  Adjust spacing as you see fit.

#### Output

```
> python3 test.py
Enter the no. of rows: 10
                  1
                1   1
              1   2   1
            1   3   3   1
          1   4   6   4   1
        1   5   10  10  5   1
      1   6   15  20  15  6   1
    1   7   21  35  35  21  7   1
  1   8   28  56  70  56  28  8   1
1   9   36  84  126 126 84  36  9   1
```

Comment: This is best for centering.  Even if rows=20.

Answer (score 0):

```
n=int(input("Enter number of rows: "))
a=[]
for i in range(n):
    a.append([])
    a[i].append(1)
    for j in range(1,i):
        a[i].append(a[i-1][j-1]+a[i-1][j])
    if(n!=0):
        a[i].append(1)
for i in range(n):
    print("   "*(n-i),end=" ",sep=" ")   
    for j in range(0,i+1):
        print('{0:6}'.format(a[i][j]),end=" ",sep=" ")
    print()
```

The line   `print("   "*(n-i),end=" ",sep=" ")`  gives the initial spaces you are looking for.