# Python: printing 1 row of Pascal Triangle

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, tuples, pascals-triangle

New to learning python and am having some trouble understanding a solution provided?
It has to do with Pascal Triangle and printing the rows when asking a user to "enter a row number"

There were bits of the solution provided and the rest I fit in (first for loop)..

```
n=int(input("Enter a row number: "))
a=[]
for i in range(n):
    a.append([])
    a[i].append(1)
    for j in range(1,i):
        a[i].append(a[i-1][j-1]+a[i-1][j])
    if(n!=0):
        a[i].append(1)
for i in range(n):
    print("   "*(n-i),end=" ",sep=" ")
    for j in range(0,i+1):
        print('{:4}'.format(a[i][j]),end=" ")
    print()
```

My question is which part of the code is printing the triangle structure? I assume the last for loop?
Also if I wanted to just print 1 row, what would I be changing?
EX: Input: 5 and output would be [1 4 6 4 1 ]

Thank you and any help/advice would be appreciated

Comment: Please assign a fixed value to `n`, e.g. `n=5`, ideally do the same for `a`. Also please provide the output of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the last loop is printing every row of the triangle. To print any specific row, jut run the second loop with specific value of `i`.

Before that, there is an easier way to more forward. Let's consider the output of below code:

```py
n = 7
a = []
for i in range(n):
    a.append([])
    a[i].append(1)
    for j in range(1, i):
        a[i].append(a[i - 1][j - 1] + a[i - 1][j])
    if (n != 0):
        a[i].append(1)

print(a)
```

The output is:

```
[[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 3, 1], [1, 4, 6, 4, 1], [1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1], [1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1]]
```

From this 2d array, you can decide which single element you want to print. For example at index 4 you have `[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]`. From these values in the array `a` you can figure out which row to print.

Now for `5` if you want `[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]`, you can simply do the following:

```py
n = 7
a = []
for i in range(n):
    a.append([])
    a[i].append(1)
    for j in range(1, i):
        a[i].append(a[i - 1][j - 1] + a[i - 1][j])
    if (n != 0):
        a[i].append(1)

to_print = 5
for i in range(0, len(a[to_print-1])):
    print(a[to_print-1][i], end=" ")
```

The output will be:

```
1 4 6 4 1
```

Comment: Could you explain what is happening in the for loop after to_print? Just to make sure..
I understand so far that to_print is 5 so in the for loop, we are looking at the range 0 to last row i want. and then prints the last row with space in between?

Comment: `a` is a 2d array, in which each element represent a row in Pascal's triangle. Now you want the row at index 4. We are looping through 0 to the size of array at index 4. At index 4 the array is : 1, 4, 6, 4, 1. So we are looping from 0 to 4, as the size of this array is 5. We are printing each element.

Answer (score 1):

@riam_98, would you like to try this version: It's simplified the logic/flow to take advantage of `Pascal` key characteristics.

More reading can be found here - [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle)

```
from typing import List


def getRow(index: int) -> List[int]:

    row = [1]       # firsts row

    if index == 1:  return row

    for i in range(index-1):
        for j in range(i, 0, -1):
            row[j] = row[j] + row[j-1]
        row.append(1)
    return row


print(getRow(2))
print(getRow(3))
print(getRow(4))
print(getRow(5))
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]   # 5th
```

Answer (score 1):

> if I wanted to just print 1 row, what would I be changing?

I believe the answers given (and accepted) so far do *too much work* to obtain the values for an individual row.  If we look at [Calculating a row or diagonal by itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pascal%27s_triangle#Calculating_a_row_or_diagonal_by_itself) in the Wikipedia page that @DanielHao recommends, we can generate a simpler solution:

```
n = int(input("Enter a row number: "))

numbers = [1]

for k in range(1, n):
    numbers.append(numbers[-1] * (n - k) // k)

print(numbers)
```

We don't need to generate the *entire triangle* up to the row we desire nor use *nested loops* to calculate it.

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
Enter a row number: 5
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
> python3 test.py
Enter a row number: 10
[1, 9, 36, 84, 126, 126, 84, 36, 9, 1]
>
```

> which part of the code is printing the triangle structure? I assume
> the last for loop?

Yes, but note that it is a fragile, limited solution due to the hardcoding of the number width:

```
print('{:4}'.format(a[i][j]),end=" ")
```

For smaller values, the triangle is lopsided, and for values larger than 16, it loses all its symmetry.  Here's an example of a [Pascal's triangle output that self adjusts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65403552/5771269)  Compare it's output to the solution you're asking about.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's unfortunate it only appears at the bottom (and had zero votes!?!?).